# Python lambda character

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that includes a parameter lambda as a character. However, lambda is a tool in python so how do I write lambda as a character in python without having it be the tool.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I am not understanding what you mean.

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: are you saying you want to have a parameter that is named `lambda`?

Comment: `lambda` is a reserved word in Python, and cannot be used as an ordinary identifier. But what to do mean "lambda as a character?"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think he means the triangular symbol

Comment: Answer: You can't.

Comment: Do you mean lambda as in the literal "λ" which is the unicode code point "\u03bb"?

Comment: I hope you mean lambda, the greek alphabet!

Comment: @TankorSmash The "triangular symbol" is called Delta, not Lambda.

Comment: @DYZ perhaps he ment the uppercase lambda, like on the Spartan shields.

Comment: @DYZ I was going off the Half life 2 symbol, which is called the Lambda character http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lambda Maybe you're right and I'm just totally out of my element though

Comment: I'm sorry, I realized I wasn't specific enough.  

Yes, I want the greek letter λ as a parameter in my function. However, I am using Jupyer notebook. And when i use λ as one of my parameters it gives me an invalid syntax

Answer (score 5):

If you want a function such as

```
def try_lambda (lambda):
    print lambda
```

... you cannot do this.  **lambda** is a reserved word to introduce a lambda function, and you cannot use it for something else.

If, instead, you want to use the Greek character:

```
def try_lambda (λ):
    print (λ)
```

... then you *can* do this.  The above code works in Python 3.*, which defaults to UTF-8

Under Python 2.*, you have to declare your program as using a different character set (the default is an English-centric character set).  See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) for encoding details.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def try_lambda (λ):
    print λ
```

Comment: What do you mean "declare your program as using a different character set"? Python (3 at least) supports writing source code in UTF-8 by default, AFAIK.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of the file. The default set is ASCII.

Comment: @DYZ what do you mean "the default set?". AFAIK, Python defaults to UTF-8, at least on Python 3.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: good point, both you and DYZ.  I was leaving this to OP to look up, but let's do it well.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga "Python will default to ASCII as standard encoding if no other  encoding hints are given." https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Comment: @DYZ, yea, sure, but that was for Python 2.3, and that PEP was written almost 2 decades ago.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oops, sorry, didn't look at the version.

Comment: @DYZ read this section of the docs for Python 3.6: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code

Comment: I'm sorry, I realized I wasn't specific enough.

Comment: Yes, I want the greek letter λ as a parameter in my function. However, I am using Jupyer notebook. And when i use λ as one of my parameters it gives me an invalid syntax

Comment: Right -- it's not part of the default character set.  You need to start your notebook file with a **coding** line for an encoding that includes the characters you want to use.  **# coding: utf-8** is a typical one.  Search for "Jupyter coding UTF" for extra help.